# How to have: map<T, vector<iterator to map itself> >?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

I need a `map` whose keys are of some composite type `T` to a vector of *iterators of the map itself*.
(e.g., think of a graph in which every node holds iterators that point to its parents.)

The reason I'm avoiding storing the parents' *keys* as values is that the keys are expensive objects, so I'd like to store iterators instead.

Is such a thing possible?
If not, what's the best alternative?

(I know I can use polymorphism and type erasure as a brute-force way to solve this, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.)

Comment: Is there a specific reason that the links to the parents are in the form of iterators?

Comment: @Jon: I kept them as iterators because I might need to traverse the map with them later. What else could I use though? I don't think pointers would change anything would they?

Comment: The thing is, traverse the map how -- i.e., does the map ordering somehow correspond to the graph's structure? If not then how is traversing the map important (vs traversing the graph which is obviously important)?

Comment: @Jon: Just to copy everything up to that node, for example. It's not terribly important -- if you have other ideas do mention them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to 23.2.1 General container requirements:

```
Containers are objects that store other objects. They control allocation
and deallocation of these objects through constructors, destructors, 
insert and erase operations.
```

Hence it is possible:

```
struct Key;
struct Value;
typedef std::map<Key, Value> Map;

struct Key {};
struct Value {
    std::vector<Map::iterator> parents;
};
```

(All types and sizes are known)

Comment: +1 wow this is awesome! I guess it's not guaranteed to work but it's good enough for me, thanks!

Comment: Well, the issue is that `std::map` doesn't necessarily allow incomplete types as an argument, so `map<Key, Value>` doesn't necessarily work because `Value` isn't defined at that point. But that's not really a problem for me because if it doesn't work on some compiler, I can just switch to `boost::container::map` and it will be fine. Thanks though! :)

Comment: @Mehrdad Ouote from 4.3.1 Template type argument: "[ Note: A template type argument may be an incomplete type (3.9). — end note ]"

Comment: @Mehrdad If you read the accepted answer carefully "when instantiating a template". The declaration above does not instantiate.

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually you are right, there is the instantiation of map::iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to store a smart pointer to the parent rather than an iterator.